# Make Exoplayer a Stereographic view like google cardboard

Tags: rtsp, exoplayer, rtmp, vrvideoview

I'm trying to use Exoplayer to play a RTSP/RTMP stream in 360, it worked well and I can see the streaming in 360 dragging with my finger. But now i can't watch the video like in Google Cardboard with a separated view for each eye. If anyone can give me a solution to watch RTMP/RSTP streaming in android studio with left/right view I would be very grateful.

I send a photo of the kind of playerview I need [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18wb3.png)

I tried to use a webview and set a rtsp videoplayer in web, but the current versions of the players I found like Clappr or Videojs doesn't support RTMP/RTSP

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.